# Dumping data structure to JSON in Python raises unorderable types str and builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm trying to call Flask's `jsonify` on a data structure, but I get `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < builtin_function_or_method()`. How do I fix this error?

```
bucketlists = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': "BucketList1",
    'items': [{
        id: 1,
        'name': "I need to do X",
        'date_created': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
        'date_modified': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
        'done': False
    }],
    'date_created': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
    'date_modified': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
    'created_by': "1113456"
}]

@app.route('/bucketlists/', methods=['GET'])
def get_bucketlists():
    return jsonify({'bucketlists': bucketlists})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) is a builtin Python function; `jsonify` cannot serialize it, you need to wrap the dictionary key with quotes to make it a string:

```
bucketlists = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': "BucketList1",
    'items': [{
        'id': 1, # -----> Here
        'name': "I need to do X",
        'date_created': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
        'date_modified': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
        'done': False
    }],
    'date_created': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
    'date_modified': "2015-08-12 11:57:23",
    'created_by': "1113456"
}]
```

Additionally, you need to add double underscores to access the name of the  module :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```